# multiple skype login using single instance?

Tags: skype, instant-messaging, multiple-instances, skype4java

Can anyone please tell me how to create multiple instance of skype with different logins.(imo.im for example allows multiple skype users to login and chat).By somehow I read that using Dbus-skype client it is possible but I dont know how exactly its possible.Skype API only works for a single user after logging into the skype client manually,but I need this for multiple user.Any idea,please help me with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In response to your initial inquiry, the way to run a second instance of Skype in Windows is as shown below, but seeing as I don't have many Skype accounts I can't test it for any more than that. The way to run two (maybe more?) instances simultaneously is to create a shortcut with a '/secondary' after the double quotes in the "Target" field of the shortcut properties, like so...

[image]

**Windows**: Here's a nice [tutorial](http://www.axelsegebrecht.com/blog/how-to/run-multiple-instances-of-skype/) for it as well. I sure hope this answers your question. I could sure use the rep. [^.^]

---

EDIT: I did a little research into D-Bus so I thought I'd update my answer as well to make it easier for those who find this post in the future. Please note, that as of this post I haven't tested this because I haven't had time to get my dual-boot or VMware setup for Linux, but these links seem quite credible.

**D-Bus**: For starters, I found this [AWESOME PDF](http://d3s.mff.cuni.cz/publications/download/SkypeDemoTechnicalReport.pdf) on how to set it up, including scripting, controlling, all kinds of goodies. In addition, here are a couple forum posts on the Skype API that talk a bit about it:

[Post 1](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=40162) :: [Post 2](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=52187)
The gist is that something like this "sudo -u otheruser skype --use-session-dbus" from terminal ought to work.

Happy Skyping :D

Comment: I already read about this,the above technique will eat lot of computer memory and the number instance is limited and I guess skype might even ban you if they track many accounts running from a single IP.All I want to know is...Can i login in single account through that would I be able to manage multiple login's,I just want to know if this is possible or not.You know imo.im(similar to that), i am really surprised how they do.

Comment: Hmmm, somehow I seriously doubt you'd get banned seeing as how they tell you HOW to run two instances in their support section ([here](https://support.skype.com/en-us/faq/FA829/How-can-I-run-two-Skype-accounts-on-the-same-computer?frompage=search&q=multiple+instances&fromSearchFirstPage=false)) lol. Anyway, I never really had an issue with system resources, even on systems with 4Gb memory. I'll try to give it another look tomorrow though if you haven't found an answer yet. Thanks for the up though :)

Comment: Well,am not talking about running just 2/3 instances...am talking about some 500 or 800 instances.

Comment: @kiddo : Oh my gosh, you're gonna love me. I found this awesome [PDF](http://d3s.mff.cuni.cz/publications/download/SkypeDemoTechnicalReport.pdf) on how to set it up, including scripting, controlling, all kinds of goodies. If that's not enough, check these out too:
http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=40162
http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=52187
I sure hope you get this in time. 50 rep >> 25 :D

Comment: I will give you 50 rep - just for your interest in answering my question.But these documents i have already read it.I must go in a different way to solve this issue.

Comment: Marked Answered - just for your interest in answering me.

Comment: @kiddo Well I sure appreciate it. I'm sorry that wasn't of more help, I really tried my best. I'm actually quite surprised that those links didn't help. Maybe you have some conflicting settings in your Linux or something? Anyway, good luck and thanks again. :D